# Flutter use reusable method in class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, I want to create classes that encompass some functionality of my code. Example here, I have a class that manages my notifications.

As you can see I set the status of my notifications to be able to use them more easily. I have a success status, an error, etc ... but for now I have to rewrite all the code in each method.

How do I set the appearance of a default notification and then inject this code into my methods? In each method I want to be able to change the title and description but I don't want to change the colors manually. They must be defined in my method.

**My class :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flushbar/flushbar.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/colors.dart';

class MyInfoBar extends Flushbar {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  MyInfoBar({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
  });

  Future information(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Flushbar(
      flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
      duration:  Duration(seconds: 3),
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.info_outline,
        size: 28.0,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      shouldIconPulse : false,
      backgroundColor: MyColors.colorContrastPurple,
      titleText: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white)),
      messageText: Text(description, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.white)),
    ).show(context);
  }

  Future success(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Flushbar(
      flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
      duration:  Duration(seconds: 3),
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.check_circle_outline,
        size: 28.0,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      shouldIconPulse : false,
      backgroundColor: MyColors.colorContrastGreen,
      titleText: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white)),
      messageText: Text(description, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.white)),
    ).show(context);
  }

  Future error(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Flushbar(
      flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
      duration:  Duration(seconds: 3),
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.error_outline,
        size: 28.0,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      shouldIconPulse : false,
      backgroundColor: MyColors.colorContrastRed,
      titleText: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white)),
      messageText: Text(description, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.white)),
    ).show(context);
  }
}
```

And when I want to use it :

```
MyInfoBar(title: "title", description: "description",).information(context);
```

Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there!

```
class MyInfoBar extends Flushbar {
    
    // No need to store the values

    MyInfoBar({
        @required String title,
        @required String description,
        FlushbarPosition flushbarPosition = FlushbarPosition.TOP, // This is a default value. If you do not pass this property to the constructor, FlushbarPosition.TOP will be considered
        Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 3), // Same here but notice the const keyword. This is because default values should always be constant
        bool shouldIconPulse = false,
        // Other properties here and their default values. If you specify no default value, they will be null.
    }) : super( // Now send these properties to the parent which is Flushbar
            titleText: Text(title), // add default styling if you want
            messageText: Text(description),
            duration: duration,
            shouldIconPulse: shouldIconPulse,
            // Etc.
        );
    // So what we are doing here is creating a Flushbar with some default properties and naming it MyInfoBar.
    // Now whenever you instantiate MyInfoBar, you get the default notification and you can of course adjust the properties.
    
    // Static methods are cleaner in this context as in your example,
    // you are instantiating this class but only using it to instantiate 
    // a new Flushbar thus eliminating the purpose of the first object you created.
    static Future success({
        @required String title,
        @required String description,
        @required BuildContext context
    }) {
        return MyInfoBar(title: title, description: description).show(context); // Other properties get the default values as you have not specified any here.
    } 

    // Similarly you can define other methods.
}
```

Now to access it:

```
MyInfoBar.success(title: "Hello World", description: "Beep boop!", context: context);
```

I wrote this code here directly so there may be some typos but, I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you I see how to do now